# How to Update Signalr Data in React Component

Tags: reactjs, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm testing out turning a component that gets data from a json endpoint to getting continuous updates from a signlar endpoint for a operations dashboard. What I've read on blogs and SO is that in 2021 we should use **@microsoft/signalr** on the react side to communicate with a signalr endpoint.

Below is my testing code, it receives data from the signalr endpoint and updates the state of the component, but the ShimmeredDetailsList doesn't get redrawn with the data. Suggestions / Criticisms on what needs changed here to update data once, on an interval (30 seconds)? Perhaps I've structured this incorrectly. Any recommendations on reading for signalr? We are trying to only use office-ui-fabric-react components.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Fabric,
  SelectionMode,
  ShimmeredDetailsList,
  Panel,
  PanelType,
  Stack,
  StackItem,
  mergeStyleSets,
  Selection,
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import { HubConnectionBuilder, HubConnectionState } from '@microsoft/signalr';

export class AccountsList extends Component {
  displayName = AccountsList.name;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.dismiss = this.dismiss.bind(this);
    this.onSelectionChange = this.onSelectionChange.bind(this);
    this.selection = new Selection({
      onSelectionChanged: () => this.onSelectionChange(),
    });
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      selectedItem: {},
      panelOpen: false,
      loaded: false,
      appId: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    /*
        fetch('/api/Accounts/Accounts')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => { this.setState({ items: data, loaded: true }) });
            */

    this.setUpSignalRConnection().then(() => {
      this.forceUpdate();
    });
  }

  async setUpSignalRConnection() {
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('/api/DashboardHub').withAutomaticReconnect().build();

    connection.on('Message', (message: string) => {
      console.log('signalr: message : ' + message);
    });
    connection.on('Accounts', (data) => {
      if (data != null) {
        this.setState({ items: data, loaded: true });
        console.log(this.state.items);
      }
    });

    try {
      await connection.start();
      console.log('signalr connection state: ' + connection.state);
      connection.invoke('GetAccounts');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('signalr: error : ' + err);
    }
  }

  columns = [
    { key: 'name', name: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 200, isResizeable: true },
    {
      key: 'currentBalance',
      name: 'Current Balance',
      fieldName: 'currentBalance',
      minWidth: 100,
      maxWidth: 400,
      isResizeable: true,
    },
    {
      key: 'maxBuyingPower',
      name: 'Buying Power',
      fieldName: 'maxBuyingPower',
      minWidth: 100,
      maxWidth: 400,
      isResizeable: true,
    },
  ];

  styles = mergeStyleSets({
    stackRoot: {
      height: '100%',
    },
    header: {
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    content: {
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      padding: 10,
    },
  });

  dismiss() {
    this.setState({ panelOpen: false });
  }

  onSelectionChange() {
    if (!this.selection) {
      return;
    }
    const selectedItem = this.selection.getSelection()[0];
    if (selectedItem) {
      //this.setState({ selectedItem: selectedItem, panelOpen: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fabric>
        <ShimmeredDetailsList
          setKey="set"
          items={this.state.items}
          enableShimmer={!this.state.loaded}
          columns={this.columns}
          selectionMode={SelectionMode.single}
          selection={this.selection}
        />
        <Panel isOpen={this.state.panelOpen} type={PanelType.medium} isLightDismiss="true" onDismiss={this.dismiss}>
          <Stack vertical className={this.styles.stackRoot}>
            <StackItem></StackItem>
            <br />
            <StackItem grow></StackItem>
          </Stack>
        </Panel>
      </Fabric>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help Mario; I was unaware we could configure the language in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm also kind of new to this but recently I managed to use signalr for one of my projects. I was reading some articles on the internet and yes, you will need to use ASP .NET Core and @microsoft/signalr on your react app.

In my project I managed to make it work with signalr no jQuery but on my backend project I'm using ASP .NET Framework.

Also, I don't understand why you need to make a request every 30 seconds. The thing with signalr is that it automatically send the request when something gets updated based on what do you need. For example if one of your react client will send a message , the message will go to the API and there the server will send the message for all users.

Example of my code:

```
      let connection = new 
      hubConnection('https://localhost:
      44384/signalr/hubs');
      let hubProxy = 
      connection.createHubProxy('HubSignalR');
      let hubProxy = 
      connection.createHubProxy('HubSignalR');

      hubProxy.on('pushNewElement', 
      function(message) {
      console.log(message);
      });
      console.log(hubProxy);

      connection.start({ jsonp: true ,    transport: 
      ['webSockets'], useDefaultPath: false 
      })
      .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, 
      connection ID=' + connection.id);

      hubProxy.invoke('SendElement',  "hey!" 
      ).done(function  () {
      console.log ('Invocation succeeded');
      }).fail(function (error) {
      console.log('Invocation failed. Error: ' + 
      error);
      });

      })
      .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not 
      connect'); });
      console.log(connection);



      connection.disconnected(function () {
      // Try to reconnect after 5 seconds
      setTimeout(function () {
      
      connection.start({ jsonp: true , transport: [ 
      'webSockets'] })
        .done(function(){ console.log('Now 
      connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);
       })
        .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not 
      connect'); });
      }, 5000);
      });
```

The hubProxy.on() is the function that will be executed when the server sends back the message. Also 'pushNewElement' needs to be the exact thing from your hub otherwise it will not work.

The `hubProxy.invoke()` is the function that will send the message to the server so if you declare your connection and hubproxy before the component class  you will can use it in any other function in your component class. Also the string inside invoke('myFunc', ...) will have to be the same as in your API.

In C#:

```
[HubName("HubSignalR")]
public class HubSignalR : Hub
{
    [HubMethodName("SendElement")]
    public void SendElement(string message)
    {
        IHubContext context = 
        GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.
        GetHubContext("HubSignalR");
        context.Clients.All.pushNewElement(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will test this out. My concern for non-real time is can/should I solution all dashboards data feeds as signalr if say the underlying data only changes every 5 minutes for some databoard data and others change every second. That way we are using the same pattern everywhere instead of two.